# Boost : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file (lib)

Tags: python, c++, boost

I've red all topics about boost problems i think, but my problem is different:
I am receiving an error in my VS :
`1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'C:\boost_1_72_0\stage\lib\boost_python37-vc140-mt-gd-x32-1_67.lib'`
I have installed again with b2 & bootstrap command in VS all libs again. those names for python are :
eg:`libboost_python37-vc141-mt-gd-x32-1_72`
why VS is asking me for `vc140` and `1_67` in the name of this lib ? 
And how can I solve it?

Comment: It seems that Boost has a different opinion concerning the compiler version that you're using. This happens when you install for one compiler and then try to use a different one.

Comment: it seems so, i remember that i had problems with 1.67 and I ve installed 1.72, how can i change it?

Comment: do you checked if you have some `C:\boost_1_72_0\stage\lib\boost_python*` library version in your output lib directory ? i suppose NO

Comment: no I dont have, thats the problem VS is trying to take libraries from 1.67. How to change this option that @UlrichEckhardt mention above?

Answer (score 0):

Problem reason mentioned in comments, one boost version (1.67) installed before.
Solution: 
in boost docs found:
`https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/more/getting_started/windows.html`

```
Build From the Visual Studio IDE
From Visual Studio's File menu, select New > Project…

In the left-hand pane of the resulting New Project dialog, select Visual C++ > Win32.

In the right-hand pane, select Win32 Console Application (VS8.0) or Win32 Console Project (VS7.1).

In the name field, enter “example”

Right-click example in the Solution Explorer pane and select Properties from the resulting pop-up menu

In Configuration Properties > C/C++ > General > Additional Include Directories, enter the path to the Boost root directory, for example

C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_72_0

In Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Precompiled Headers, change Use Precompiled Header (/Yu) to Not Using Precompiled Headers.2

Replace the contents of the example.cpp generated by the IDE with the example code above.

From the Build menu, select Build Solution.
```